# How to select a Python virtual environment in LunarVim

Tags: python, virtualenv, neovim, lunarvim

I want to select a Python virtual environment for each of my different Python projects within LunarVim. In VSCode this would be "F1 -> Select Python Interpreter". How can I do this in LunarVim?

Answer (score 0):

I use this [swenv.nvim](https://github.com/AckslD/swenv.nvim) plugin to solve this problem.